# Problems trying to implement this layout

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm trying to design the following layout using flutter for a website, but I can't figure out the right pattern for doing so.
[image]

I tried many possibilities with columns and rows; I tried also using a stack, but whatever I use, either 3-4 won't become scrollable, or 5 won't take the height that it's given. Is there a workaround for this layout to be implemented?

Comment: Try using grid with different sizes for elements, Grid layout should work,

Comment: I saw the StairedGridTile from the Staggered Grid View package, but I'm not really sure whether that will work or not, since every widget in the layout is something completely different than the other

Comment: Please try them, because there are always solutions that we can do.

Comment: I tried them, and they worked fine, but one problem I'm facing is how can i change the the content when clicking on any of the tab bars (content is nr 3, 4, 5, and 6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily accomplish what you want using this library.

[flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)

If you want your layout to take up entire screen, key is to use percentages of screen height for `mainAxisExtent` of `StaggeredGridTile.extent`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: AppView(),
    ),
  );
}

class AppView extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var list = List<int>.generate(100, (i) => i);

    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      body: StaggeredGrid.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        axisDirection: AxisDirection.down,
        mainAxisSpacing: height * 0.015,
        crossAxisSpacing: height * 0.015,
        children: [
          StaggeredGridTile.extent(
            crossAxisCellCount: 1,
            mainAxisExtent: height * 0.08,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
          ),
          StaggeredGridTile.extent(
            crossAxisCellCount: 1,
            mainAxisExtent: height * 0.08,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
          ),
          StaggeredGridTile.extent(
            crossAxisCellCount: 1,
            mainAxisExtent: height * 0.08,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
          ),
          StaggeredGridTile.extent(
            crossAxisCellCount: 2,
            mainAxisExtent: height * 0.08,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
          StaggeredGridTile.extent(
            crossAxisCellCount: 1,
            mainAxisExtent: height * 0.675,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          StaggeredGridTile.extent(
            crossAxisCellCount: 1,
            mainAxisExtent: height * 0.81,
            // mainAxisCellCount: 1.2,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.pink,
              child: ListView(
                children: list.map((e) => Text(e.toString())).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          StaggeredGridTile.extent(
            crossAxisCellCount: 1,
            mainAxisExtent: height * .58,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: ListView(
                children: list.map((e) => Text(e.toString())).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          StaggeredGridTile.extent(
            crossAxisCellCount: 2,
            mainAxisExtent: height * .23,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.teal,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for sharing this, it helped but, i faced a problem of not being able to scroll through the lists no matter what i try, I ended up doing it in a way way more complicated way. using rows/columns and a stack for nr 6.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this**

[image]

```
  Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Container(
          height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 2,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                            width: double.infinity,
                            height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 8,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 1,
                              width: 1,
                              child: const ColoredBox(color: Colors.amber),
                            )),
                        Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 2,
                              child: Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                  height:
                                      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 3,
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    height: 1,
                                    width: 1,
                                    child:
                                        const ColoredBox(color: Colors.amber),
                                  )),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                  height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) /
                                      7.5,
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    height: 1,
                                    width: 1,
                                    child:
                                        const ColoredBox(color: Colors.amber),
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                        height: ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 4) + 12,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 1,
                          width: 1,
                          child: const ColoredBox(color: Colors.amber),
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                    width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 3.8,
                    height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 5,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 1,
                      width: 1,
                      child: const ColoredBox(color: Colors.amber),
                    )),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a github project for design a responsive screen.

The github link [Flutter-Responsive-Admin-Panel-or-Dashboard](https://github.com/abuanwar072/Flutter-Responsive-Admin-Panel-or-Dashboard)

[image]

Comment: I saw this one, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for, that layout can be easily made, but with mine there is a problem either with nr5 and nr6

Comment: okey @Steinhammer71  , I try to solve